# Disconnected no supported authentication methods available

Tags: centos, ssh, ssh-keys

Yes, I'm aware questions like this already exist, and I've already checked quite a few out, but the methods were unable to help me. I am running CentOS 6 on my VPS. This error occurs when I try to log into the username while connecting with PuTTY.

I am trying to log into a user. The path is /home/[name].
Here are my sshd_config settings (it's not on default port):

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_key
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

The authorized_key contains the public key. I am relatively new to Linux, so any tips would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried adding the private key to PuTTY, and now it just says "Server refused our key", and the same error message pops up.

Comment: Are you able to log in using password authentication?

Comment: @Paul I've just changed it to check, yes I can.

Comment: Did you use PuTTYgen to generate your key pair?

Comment: @Paul I copied the content of the  [name] file (not [name].pub) and I've saved it to a text file. Then I imported it to PuTTYgen and saved it as a ppk file.

Comment: You should check the the relevant logs: /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages for any clue as to why auth is failing. Generally it's a permissions problem on the .ssh directory or the files contained within.

Comment: @Paul for the actual keygen I did it in ssh.

Comment: @BrettLevene I only found little logs for today: http://pastebin.com/rQTsmkXS

Comment: Out of needless paranoia, I only use keys generated on the device that is originating the connection. Anyone who has access to your VPS may also gain access to everything else that key pair is used for. I believe CentOS uses `/var/log/secure` for login logs. You should see all log ins and log in attempts, including your successful password log in.

Comment: @Paul here is my successful attempt followed by the unsuccessful one: http://pastebin.com/ErW2f5JH

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/user/.ssh/authorized_key`? Linux has strict requirements for permissions on that file. I always have it as 600.

Comment: @Paul I've noticed that you put authorized_key and mine is called authorized_keys, but anyway the permission is -rw-rw-r--

Comment: The config file posted in your question states `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_key`, so that is where it will look for keys.

Comment: Try changing either the name of the file to `authorized_key` or the name in the config file to `authorized_keys` and set permissions to `600` with `chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_key`.

Comment: @Paul I've set it both to "authorized_keys" now, still the same error.

Comment: You also need to restart the service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48029/discussion-between-paul-and-arraying).

Comment: I now remember that I had something similar a couple of years ago; it turns out when I pasted the public key into authorized_keys it had line breaks in it. Try to open your pub key so it's on one line and try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux is very sensitive to permissions settings.

From your home directory, you should have the following:

```
user@server:~$ ls -alF .ssh/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Oct 30 04:39 ./
drwxr-x--- 5 user user 4096 Nov  5 15:50 ../
-rw------- 1 user user 1457 Oct 30 00:55 authorized_keys
```